# Run Spring Boot Project with base directory - localhost:8080/demo/

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot

I have setup a run configuration in eclipse but it's running in localhost:8080 but I want it to run in localhost:8080/demo/ but it's not working. I have attached the run configuration and application properties file
[image]

[image]

can anyone help me to run spring boot project in localhost:8080/demo/

Comment: To start with, you shouldn't be using the "Maven target" (a sledgehammer) instead of running your main class as a regular Java application (a scalpel) or using Run As Spring Boot App with the Spring Tools plugins/Eclipse distribution (a singing-and-dancing scalpel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can just add this to your properties file

```
server.servlet.context-path=/demo
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller by annotation `@RequestMapping(path = "/demo")` or by annotation on method `@GetMapping("/demo")`